# Active Directory - Application security purpose

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am fairly new to Active directory and trying to understand it especially from application roles perspective.

I understand the use of Active Directory for authenticating internal corporate users and to implementing SSO across different applications.
What I am trying to gather are scenarios where Active directory can be used for application security ? Is it limited to creating domain users for application to use when interacting with other applications or are there other scenarios where it can be used ?

Example, in below diagram AD DS server has been added to the application landscape for 'computer objects for the failover cluster and its associated clustered roles are created in Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS)'. What does it really mean ?

[image: Web Application- AD Server]

Answer (score 1):

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) provides secure and seamless access to cloud and on-premises applications. Users can sign in once to access Office 365 and other business applications from Microsoft, thousands of software as a service (SaaS) applications, on-premises applications, and line of business (LOB) apps. Besides, enabling single sign-on (SSO) across applications and Office 365 provides a superior sign in experience for existing users by reducing or eliminating sign in prompts. For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-application-management).
[image]

And Azure AD Domain Services provides managed domain services. You can consume these domain services without the need for you to deploy, manage, and patch domain controllers in the cloud. Azure AD Domain Services integrates with your existing Azure AD tenant, thus making it possible for users to log in using their corporate credentials. 
For the details about Azure AD Domain Services, please read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview).

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks!